# vscode intellisense not working with PyTorch

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm using a virtual environment and I have selected the right interpreter.

Now even after I `cmd + p > reload window` and

```
import torch.nn as nn
```

I don't get any suggestion righting `nn.` on vscode 1.31.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found `jedi` to be quite slow but the recently released Pylance extension works like a charm: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release

and then update your settings

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance"
```

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same problem with vscode 1.42. Resolved the problem by going to *Settings*, Changing *Python: Language server* from *Microsoft* to *Jedi*. Now I can see autocomplete with *torch.nn*.

Answer (score 0):

Using the beta version of the Python language server (0.2.17), I get completions.

[image: <code>from torch import nn</code> with completions]

To turn on the language server, follow [these instructions](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3977). If the stable version doesn't work then follow those instructions on how to download the beta version of the extension to get the completions.

Comment: In my case in version 1.33.1, this works, but for other modules such as torch.randn, I get no intellisense, instead I get the infamous `Module 'torch' has no 'randn' memberpylint(no-member)` error! Will  this fix this issue or is it something completely different?

Comment: @Breeze it's potentially the same. No way to know unless you try. :) And if the Python language server doesn't work then please file a bug against the Python language server.

Comment: I gave it a try and Language server indeed fixes that issue, but there are 2 issues here, it doesnt work on namespaces such as `cuda`, or `nn`. you wont get intellisense for `torch.nn`, or `torch.cuda`, the only way to get them to work is to have them imported manually like what you did here! 
Also its very crude in terms of appearance, compared to `Jedi`. Jedi is much more userfriendly! any plan on making it more appealing in that terms?

Comment: @Breeze By "crude" do you mean the appearance of the docstrings? If so then please upvote https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/38 .

Comment: @Breeze then please upvote the [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/38) tracking the feature request to change docstring presentation

Comment: Did so  2 days ago!